# Make ComboBox Search List as User Types

Tags: combobox, acrobat

I have been researching this for weeks now, and have not been able to locate what should be a simple solution to a simple problem. I have an Adobe Pro XI form with a ComboBox that has a very large list -- over 500 -- for the user to select from. Currently, the ComboBox only responds to the first letter typed, so that if the name the user is looking for begins "Lor...", when the "L" is pressed it will scroll to the top of the "L's", but then when the "o" is pressed, it scrolls to the top of the "o's", and so-on. Is there an easy solution to script this so that it will scroll through the list as the user types? Optimally, I'd like to be able to use a Document level script that I can then activate On Focus from the Actions tab of the ComboBox Properties dialog. I have found some solutions to this problem for other applications, but have not been able to find something that works for Adobe Acrobat Pro. Note that I am not a programmer, I am the company accountant and am trying to fix a form. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Good question. I'm not familiar with the program, most of the site probably isn't, so I wonder if there's a specific stack exchange that can be more helpful for this question. Just thinking out loud. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps try superuser.com, a stack exchange site targeted towards hardware and software use, seems to be pretty active with the adobe tag.

Comment: Thanks, Goose! I'll try them out.

Answer (score 0):

Combo boxes become rather cumbersome when they have a high number of entries (in older References, it was suggested to not go beyond 50 or so entries).

It does require a little bit more programming, but using a popup in this situation, together with a field in which the result will be written, is more efficient and ergonomic, because popups can be multilevel, which means, you could group everything between A and D in one level, everything between E and H, and so on.

Have a look at `app.popupMenuEx()` in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

FWIW, with a little bit more scripting, such multilevel popups can be created dynamically on the fly; personal experience shows that to build up such a popup with no more than 35 selections at the farthest level, and a total of 1500 or so selections takes less than a second.

Comment: Thanks, Max Wyss. I took a look at this, but it won't resolve my problem. I have 40 names that begin with "L" in the list. I really need a method for scrolling the list as the user types. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.